# Why is the DNS server on a VPN connection different than the DNS server on a Wi-Fi connection in Android?

Tags: vpn, dns

I have a small VpnService on Android, and I set DNS 1.1.1.1' in it, but in the Wi-Fi DNS settings the server shows it as '10.0.2.3' or something similar.
If you try to look through the “Net Analyzer” program, there are two sections VPN and Wi-Fi and there are two different dns (one that I installed, the second one in the settings)

Comment: A VPN is designed to tunnel all traffic to the VPN server. When VPN was designed DNS servers were located next to the "internet entry point" thus a VPN server as new entry point has it's own DNS setting which is used when the VPN is active.